# If $ \tan \left( x \right) +\tan \left( x+\frac{\pi}{3} \right) +\tan \left( x+\frac{2\pi}{3} \right) =3 $ prove that ..

Tags: trigonometry

If
$$
\tan \left( x \right) +\tan \left( x+\frac{\pi}{3} \right) +\tan \left( x+\frac{2\pi}{3} \right) =3
$$

prove that $$\frac{3\tan x-\tan^3x}{1-3\tan^2x}=1$$

hints will be appreciated

thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try writing the 2nd and the 3rd $tan$ as $\sin/\cos$ and adding them together, the numerator should be of the form $\sin(x+y)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We try to simplify  $\tan \left( x+\frac{\pi}{3} \right) +\tan \left( x+\frac{2\pi}{3} \right) $. We have
$$\begin{align}
&\tan \left( x+\frac{\pi}{3} \right) +\tan \left( x+\frac{2\pi}{3} \right)  \\
=& \frac {\tan x +\sqrt {3}}{1-\sqrt {3}\tan x} + \frac {\tan x -\sqrt {3}}{1+\sqrt {3}\tan x}\\
=& \frac {\tan x  +\sqrt {3} + \sqrt {3}\tan^2 x + 3\tan x +\tan x- \sqrt {3} -\sqrt {3}\tan^2 x +3\tan x}{1-3\tan^2 x} \\
=&\frac {8\tan x}{1-3\tan^2 x}\end{align}$$

Now add this to $\tan x $ and the result follows. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is faster than others.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use these

(1) $$
\tan \left( x+\frac{2\pi}{3} \right) =\tan \left( x-\frac{\pi}{3} \right) 
$$

(2) $$\tan x+\tan y=\frac{\sin(x+y)}{\cos x\cos y}$$

Comment: your first hint is not clear, how do you get this

Comment: @TaylorTed Substitute it in equation and use trigonometric relations.

Comment: i mean proof for first hint

Comment: Proof
$$\tan(x+\frac{2\pi}{3}) = \tan(x+\pi- \frac{\pi}{3})= \tan(\pi+x- \frac{\pi}{3})=\frac{\tan\pi+\tan(x-\frac{\pi}{3})}{1-\tan\pi\tan(x-\frac{\pi}{3})}=\tan(x-\frac{\pi}{3})$$

Answer (score 1):

Let (for brevity) $y=\tan x$ and note that
$$\tan \left(x+\frac\pi3\right)=\frac{y+\sqrt 3}{1-y\sqrt 3}$$
$$\tan \left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)=\frac{y-\sqrt 3}{1+y\sqrt 3}$$
Now we have that
$$y+\frac{y+\sqrt 3}{1-y\sqrt 3}+\frac{y-\sqrt 3}{1+y\sqrt 3}=3$$

Simplify the LHS and then divide by $3$.

Answer (score 1):

[ tan(x) + √3 ] .......[ tan(x) - √3 ] 
-------------------- + --------------------- = 3 - tan (x) 
[1 - √3 tan(x)]........[1 + √3 tan(x)]

tan(x) + √3 tan²(x) + √3 + 3 tan(x) + tan(x) - √3 tan²(x) - √3 + 3 tan(x) 
--------------------------------------... = 3 - tan (x) 
LCM = [1 - √3 tan(x)]*[1 + √3 tan(x)]

8 tan(x) 
-------------------- = 3 - tan (x) ; use (a + b)*)(a - b) = a² - b² in the DEN 
[1 - 3 tan²(x)]

8 tan(x) = 3 - 3*3 tan²(x) - tan(x) + 3 tan³(x) ; cross multiply

3 tan³(x) - 9 tan²(x) - 9 tan (x) + 3 = 0 ; or

tan³(x) - 3 tan²(x) - 3 tan (x) + 1 = 0 -----> Proved

Comment: This could really use some LaTeX/MathJax formatting!

Comment: new users are forgiven

Answer (score 1):

If $\tan3x=\tan 3y$

$$\frac{3\tan x-\tan^3x}{1-3\tan^2x}=\tan3y$$

$$\implies \tan^3x-3\tan3y\tan^2x-3\tan x+\tan3y=0$$

Again, as $\tan3x=\tan 3y$

$3x=180^\circ n+3y$ where $n$ is any integer  $\implies x=60^\circ n+y$ where $n\equiv0,1,2\pmod3$

So, the corresponding roots are $$\tan y,\tan(60^\circ +y), \tan(60^\circ\cdot2+y)$$

Now apply Vieta's formula.